# Automation in Windows Form Application Eating A Lot Of Ram

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am a beginner in c#, .net and developing a desktop logger application for practicing. I have developed it using Windows form application and visual studio. For the event trackers, I have used Automation Element.

Functionally, my application works as it should and writing the logs correctly. However, there is some issue with the memory which I can't seem to resolve. As long as the application stays open, it keeps on getting bigger and bigger in consuming RAM; goes 300MB+ in 15min.

It looks like it doesn't free up memory occupied by AutomationElement object. I profiled it using dotMemory 4.0 and ants memory profiler 8. It shows that automationElement objects are created but never deleted by garbage collector. Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

**EDIT 1**

Following is the full test app code along with some screenshots of the issue

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MemoryLeakTestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private AutomationElement autoelement;        
        public AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler propChangeHandler;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetBrowserProcess();
        }
        public void GetBrowserProcess()
        {


            Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
            {

                    // the chrome process must have a window
                    if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                 autoelement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);
                 SubscribePropertyChange(autoelement);
            }

        }


        public void SubscribePropertyChange(AutomationElement element)
        {
            {
                Automation.AddAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(element,
                    TreeScope.Subtree,
                    propChangeHandler = new AutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChangeChrome),
                    AutomationElement.NameProperty);                
            }
        }
        public void OnPropertyChangeChrome(object src, AutomationPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {            
            Console.WriteLine(e.NewValue);           
        }        
    }
    }
```

**When the app starts**
[image]

**When I open some tabs and do the switching:**
You can notice increase in CPU and Memory consumption
[image]

**After I stop switching for a while:** You can notice that the CPU comes back to 0% while the memory won't. It stays on there while I am expecting it to come back to its initial state just like CPU. After this step, if I start switching the tabs again, it will increase right from this point i.e 17MB to its next value and keeps on increasing
[image]

Comment: [Automation.RemoveAutomationEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation.removeautomationeventhandler) -- [Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation.removealleventhandlers) -- [Process.Dispose()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.dispose). Missing: context and usage of the code presented.

Comment: @Jimi thank you for your comment. The main purpose of my application is to log the URLs and titles of browser tabs.

Comment: "It looks like" is in general something unreliable. The actual way to analyze memory usage is to use a profiler, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019

Comment: The purpose of the code is clear: you try to get Chrome processes and use the AutomationElement derived from a main Window to attach a PropertyChange handler that detects a change in the `NameProperty`, which is usually the Text of the Element. The point is: if you do this once and never release the Handler, no problem. If you have a Timer that triggers that procedure continuously, then you have a problem. Hence, the *lack of context* and *undefined use-case* noted in my previous comment.

Comment: Get a memory snapshot and look where all these AutomationElement are created, and by which objects the are held in the memory. It will answer all you questions. And please if you use dotMemory get the latest version, how did you even manage to find v.4???

Comment: @Jimi this is the exact code I am using and using no timer at all. In the callback function OnPropertyChange, even if I don't write anything, the application grows the memory consumed by a small factor as soon as I start switching Chrome's tab. The memory stays if I don't navigate between the tab. I don't think I am releasing handler.

Comment: @Ed.ward I have used the latest trial version of dot memory, took snapshots and compared. Unfortunately, I am having difficulty understanding on how to track the issue with all those huge columns; just a beginner here :) The code in the question is the exact code I am using which has this issue.

Comment: Well, if there's no threading involved and the handler is subscribed to once (so `GetBrowserProcess()` is called once), you should have posted the code that's *switching Chrome's tabs*. Another thing that's missing is the Framework version in use.

Comment: @Jimi thank you for your continuous support. *GetBrowserProcess()* is called only on the form load; hence only once. Like I explain in my comment earlier, if you use the code above as is, you will be able to recreate the issue without having to study additional code. I can give you all of the code though no worries there.

Comment: @Jimi Please review the edited question