# Memory leak when using UI Automation in Windows 10

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, dump, microsoft-ui-automation, debugdiag

I'm experiencing a memory leak on Windows 10 machine and after investigation of some dump taken from the process causing the issue (a WPF application) I have found many instances of "MS.Internal.Automation.SynchronizedInputProviderWrapper" and basically most objects held in memory and not Garbage collected were referenced by this type.

I have been using dotMemory (key retention path of instances), Visual Studio 2019 (for dump compare) and WinDbg for further investigation.

[image]
[image]
[image]

According to this stackoverflow answer:
[UIAutomation Memory Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832122/uiautomation-memory-issue)

Their is an rollup fixing the issue on Win 8 RT & windows 2012 server:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2885482/memory-leak-when-using-ui-automation-in-windows-8

And according to Microsoft: [see this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2885482/memory-leak-when-using-ui-automation-in-windows-8)

> When multiple applications that use the UI Automation framework are
> running at the same time on a Windows 8-based computer, a memory leak
> occurs, and you experience high CPU usage.

And I think it may be the same issue on Windows 10 also but connot find a fix or rollup fixing this issue.

Update:

I did another analysis with SuperDump and found a potential explanation for the memory leak but I cannot interpret the call stack:

```
clr!EEHeapAlloc+2c   ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap 
clr!EEHeapAllocInProcessHeap+5b   clr!EEHeapAlloc 
clr!ClrAllocInProcessHeap+23    
clr!operator new+14   clr!ClrAllocInProcessHeap 
clr!ComCallWrapper::CreateWrapper+1ce   clr!operator new 
clr!ComCallWrapper::InlineGetWrapper+24   clr!ComCallWrapper::CreateWrapper 
clr!GetComIPFromObjectRef+22e   clr!ComCallWrapper::InlineGetWrapper 
clr!MarshalObjectToInterface+3a   clr!GetComIPFromObjectRef 
clr!StubHelpers::InterfaceMarshaler__ConvertToNative+d8   clr!MarshalObjectToInterface 
0x4AA1110   clr!StubHelpers::InterfaceMarshaler__ConvertToNative 
PresentationCore_ni!System.Windows.Media.DashStyle.OffsetPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)$##6001EA6 <PERF> (PresentationCore_ni+0x19cca0)    
clr!COMToCLRDispatchHelper+6b    
clr!COMPlusFrameHandlerRevCom    
UIAutomationCore!RichEditObjectProxy::QueryInterface+6139    
UIAutomationCore!NullInvoker::CallTarget    
UIAutomationCore!InProcClientAPIStub::UiaNode_GetPatternProvider    
UIAutomationCore!RichEditObjectProxy::QueryInterface+6116    
UIAutomationCore!InProcClientAPIStub::InvokeInProcAPI+5eb    
UIAutomationCore!UiaNode::CrossProcess_GetPatternProvider+49   UIAutomationCore!InProcClientAPIStub::InvokeInProcAPI 
UIAutomationCore!RemoteUiaNodeStub::Incoming_GetPatternProvider+8c   UIAutomationCore!UiaNode::CrossProcess_GetPatternProvider 
UIAutomationCore!RemoteUiaNodeStub::OnMessage+b8    
UIAutomationCore!InvokeOnCorrectContext_Callback+272    
UIAutomationCore!NullInvoker::CallTarget+2b   UIAutomationCore!InvokeOnCorrectContext_Callback 
UIAutomationCore!ProcessIncomingRequest+4f6    
UIAutomationCore!ChannelBasedServerConnection::OnData+dd    
UIAutomationCore!ReadWriteChannelInfo::Service+18a   UIAutomationCore!ChannelBasedServerConnection::OnData 
UIAutomationCore!OverlappedIOManager::IoThreadProc+b3   UIAutomationCore!ReadWriteChannelInfo::Service 
UIAutomationCore!OverlappedIOManager::StaticIoThreadProc+d   UIAutomationCore!OverlappedIOManager::IoThreadProc 
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+19    
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+2f    
ntdll!_except_handler4    
ntdll!FinalExceptionHandlerPad22    
UIAutomationCore!OverlappedIOManager::StaticIoThreadProc
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?